# How to Access minio bucket using Python API, Read in all the folders and write them as a database?

Tags: python, database, minio

I would like to access Minio using python API, read in all the folders,files,directories within in Minio Bucket
Ingest them into the script and write them into the database

any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details you have shared I would suggest you check out the initial python documentation for the minio package: [Link](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide.html)

The quick starter guide shows you quickly how to read and write files into Minio. The rest is rather open for interpretation. What database are you planning to use?